# jQuery $('element', this) selector, what does it mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I used this selector in a function and I don't even know exactly what it means, but it worked - here is my piece of code:

```
else if($(this).hasClass('list')) {
        listItem.stop(true,true).fadeOut(333, function(){ 
        var $this = $(this);
        if(listItem.hasClass('grid')) {
            $this.find('h1', this).insertBefore($this.children());
        }
```

Comment: you can only do : `find('h1')`, it make no sense to do `('h1', this)`

Comment: The title of your question and the body of your question are at odds with one another. The title talks about `$('tagname', this)`, the body talks about `.find('tagname', this)` which is a very different thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a context in the `$()` function, like this:

```
$('element', this)
```

It will then only search among the decendants of the element that `this` referens to.

It's equivalent to using the `find` method:

```
$(this).find('element')
```

Using `find` with two parameters is pointless, though. It will only ignore the second parameter.

Answer (score 7):

The ".find()" method only pays attention to one argument, so it means exactly the same thing as

```
$this.find('h1')
```

JavaScript doesn't care if you pass too many arguments to a function; in fact there's no such concept as "too many arguments".

Comment: so what if we aren't using find() - does anything take advantage of this, or what does it even mean?

Comment: @JeffJones: "[aren't] using `find`" leaves a lot of open ground. Using what instead?

Comment: @JeffJones well the question doesn't make a lot of sense; `.find()` is `.find()` and other APIs are what they are. What in particular do you mean?

Comment: I think the whole confusion here is I accidentally bolded .find(h1, this) when my question was obviously just what does (h1, this) mean, I have long since figured out what it means

Answer (score 1):

It is an [alternative selector context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context) to be used instead of the document root for the jQuery constructor.

The [`.find()` method](http://api.jquery.com/find/) will ignore any other arguments than the selector. Its search context node is given as the context of the function call.